# Rails: Retrieve latest timestamp from multiple children in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

My parent object has two children objects.

They each have updated_at and viewed_at timestamps.

i.e. a person object with some has_many/belongs_to associations

`Books: updated_at, viewed_at`

`Videos: updated_at, viewed_at`

I would like a query that just gets the latest of those four times.
i.e.

`Person.getAllBooksAndVideos.pluck(:updated_at, :viewed_at).sort{|a,b| [a.updated_at, a.viewed_at].compact.max <=> [b.updated_at, b.viewed_at].compact.max}.last`

I don't know how to do the `getAllBooksAndVideos.pluck(:updated_at, :viewed_at)` part, and any advice is very, very welcome.

Comment: I am not sure , it will work or not but can you try this query `Person.joins(:books, :videos).select("persons.*, GREATEST(books.updated_at , books.viewed_at) FROM books, GREATEST(videos.updated_at , videos.viewed_at) FROM videos )`

Answer (score 0):

You can collate all the results of the associations in an array and call sort_by on it.

`result = (person.books + person.videos).sort_by {|x| [x.updated_at, x.viewed_at]}.last`

Then you should be able to access the result as such:
`result.updated_at # This should give you your updated_at date`
`result.viewed_at # This should give you your viewed_at date`